# NoneType error .convert appear

Tags: python, threshold

i would like to do some program by capture image from webcam, then cropped it. after crop, i do some image processing and from the process it will run my robots. Here the full program:

```
import cv2
from cv2 import *
import numpy as np
import pylab
import pymorph
import mahotas
from matplotlib import pyplot
from PIL import Image 

# initialize the camera
cam = VideoCapture(0)   # 0 -> index of camera
s, img = cam.read()

# frame captured without any errors
if s:    
    imwrite("img.jpg",img) #save image

#Crop Image
imageFile = "img.jpg"
im1 = Image.open(imageFile)

def imgCrop(im):

        box = (0, 199, 640, 200)
        region = im.crop(box)
        region.save('crop.jpg')

cImg = imgCrop(im1)

#thresholding
def greyImg(im):
    gray = im.convert('L')
    bw = gray.point(lambda x: 0 if x<128 else 255, '1')
    bw.save("bw.jpg")

tImg = greyImg(cImg )

#direction

def find_centroid(im, rez):
        width, height = im.size
        XX, YY, count = 0, 0, 0
        for x in xrange(0, width, rez):
            for y in xrange(0, height, rez):
                    if im.getpixel((x, y)) == 255:
                        XX += x
                        YY += y
                        count += 1
        return XX/count, YY/count

print find_centroid(tImg, 1)

def robo_direct():
    cen = find_centroid(im, 1)
    diff = cen[0] - 320
    if diff > 10:
        print 'right'
    if diff < -10:
        print 'left'
    else:
        print 'straight'

print robo_direct()
```

The error was come out like this:

```
File "compile.py", line 32, in greyImg
gray = im.convert('L')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'convert'
```

Comment: What do you mean by `compile with another program` and `include in programming`?

Comment: Sounds like im now is None instead of an image object.

Comment: @RedX i was edit my question..please help

Answer (score 1):

That is because `im` is a `None` object.

Try again the code with:

```
print im is None
```

And you'll see. I don't know about threshold, but obviously you are creating the `im` object the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `imgCrop(im1)` has no return statement and as such returns `None`. And then your `greyImg(im)` function also has no return statement and also will return `None`.

To fix that add return statements to both functions that for the first `return region` and the second `return bw`.

Also your `robo_direct()` function should return and not print the direction so that the call to it in the statement `print robo_direct()` would print the direction.

Comment: can u explain more? because i not really understand the problem. Im new in programming so im still learning.

Comment: @timekeeper In Python functions that don't have a return statement implicitly return `None`. Those two functions don't have return statements therefore they also return `None`. As you evidently want them to return the value calculated in the function thus my suggestion of that the return statement should be for those functions.

Comment: ok thanks...i was fix it...but new problem come out..
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "compile3.py", line 51, in find_centroid
    return XX/count, YY/count
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero